# Returning a single column of Pandas dataframe *as a dataframe* after filtering on another column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume we have the following data frame `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'food' : ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs'],
                   'price' : [10, 20, 30],
                   'inventory' : ['normal', 'high', 'low']
```

I want to filter `df` and return only the elements of the `food` column with a price greater than 15.  To do so, I use:

```
the_filter = df['price'] > 15
df_filter = df[the_filter]['food']
df_filter

1    ham
2    eggs
Name: food, dtype: object
```

The problem for me is that `df_filter` is returned as a Series (I need the return to be a data frame).

```
type(df_filter)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

We can use `.loc` and get back a dataframe object:

```
df.loc[:, ['food']]
```

But how do we filter by `price`?

Comment: It's not a problem that the logical expression `df_filter` is returned as a Series, and in general we don't even assign variables for expressions like that, just use them directly to index in a `.loc[]` expression.

Comment: @smci -- edited (didn't mean to imply there was a "problem" with `.loc`).

Comment: Your issue is only with `.loc[]` syntax. Not with the filter expression being (correctly) represented as series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the condition(s) and the column(s) to return in on go with `.loc`:

```
df_filter = df.loc[df['price'] > 15, ['food']]
```

Output:

```
>>> df_filter
   food
1   ham
2  eggs

>>> type(df_filter)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use filter() as it returns same type as input object

```
df_filter = df[the_filter].filter(['food'])
type(df_filter)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```